# Upgrading from Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal)

Tags: ubuntu, boot, installation, grub, updates

I just recently installed Ubuntu 9.04 on my laptop with no problems whatsoever. I'm just now learning that 9.04 is unsupported and it's making installing software difficult. I came to the conclusion that I should just update to the latest version. I then found the latest version at the time 12.10 and made my disc so I can repeat the installation process I did for 9.04. Which brings me to my problem, I can't install 12.10 because I come across certain problems.

I have made the proper changes to my BIOS to make first boot option my CD/DVD ROM and then I get to the Ubuntu Menu:

1. **Try Ubuntu without installing** option takes me to a black screen with a blinking cursor on the top left of the screen and stays there.
2. **Install Ubuntu** option takes me to a black screen with a blinking cursor on the top left of the screen and stays there.
3. **Check disc for defects** option takes me to a black screen with a blinking cursor on the top left of the screen and stays there.
4. **Test Memory** option takes me to a blue Memtest86+ v4.20 which fails at 47% on Test #7 [Random number sequence] and leaves me no choice but to hit (ESC) to Reboot. Now assuming this was my issue then the next option wouldn't work, correct?
5. **Boot from first hard disk** option takes me to Ubuntu 9.04 and runs just fine.

Things I've seen while researching my problem is a bad iso file. I can assure you that I already validated my "ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso" file with winMd5Sum. I'm thinking it has to do with the GRUB. I have no idea what that is or how it effects my boot process.

I apologize for such a lengthy description of my problem but I hope it has given enough information so that when it is answered it helps anyone else with similar type of issues.

Below I have given screenshots of my computer. I left out the black screen with a blinking cursor because it's literally what I explained it to be.

---

Ubuntu Menu:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNTq4.jpg

Memtest86+:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGtdx.jpg

Comment: What are the specs of your machine, and how long did you wait after you selecited "Install"?

Comment: Have you read any of the 151,000 posts returned by google when looking for ["Ubuntu 12.10 black screen"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Ubuntu+12.10+black+screen)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try installing ubuntu 12.04 and than upgrading, maybe that would work, but try nomodest first, it may be quicker solution.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you can't boot you should add nomodeset as a kernel parameter. I believe you can set that under "modes" or "other options".

https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do

> nomodeset
>
> The newest kernels have moved the video mode setting into the kernel.
>   So all the programming of the hardware specific clock rates and
>   registers on the video card happen in the kernel rather than in the X
>   driver when the X server starts.. This makes it possible to have high
>   resolution nice looking splash (boot) screens and flicker free
>   transitions from boot splash to login screen. Unfortunately, on some
>   cards this doesnt work properly and you end up with a black screen.
>   Adding the nomodeset parameter instructs the kernel to not load video
>   drivers and use BIOS modes instead until X is loaded.

However, you should put away the CD, assuming you want to upgrade, and use the server install method:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1327424

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Please backup your data before you do that - whenever I did this I almost ALWAYS had issues. It was never anything critical but usually it was like an icon package that didn't get installed.